# Visual Studio: How to specify different runtime libraries for the linker? (/MTd, MDd, etc)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, dll, linker

I'm linking to a few libraries in VS2008. If my knowledge of the linker is correct, MTd is for static linking and MDd is for dynamic linking (to a DLL.) My goal is to statically link some libraries and dynamic link others. The project options seems to only have one setting for all libraries in the linker input. How would I do this?

Comment: I do not understand how that helps me. There are no parts in there about specifying linker options per-library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your project will be given a sensible C Runtime Library default after you set it up, depending on how you answer the New Project Wizard prompts.  You can inspect and alter this (if needed) as follows:

- right-click the relevant project in Solution Explorer, select Properties
- look under Configuration Properties, C/C++, Code Generation, Runtime Library.

Other libraries can be linked however you want, you just specify the library to link to under Linker, Input, Additional Dependencies.

Even if you are linking to a DLL, it will still have a .LIB file (of the correct form for a DLL) to resolve external references, unless you are manually loading the DLL and discovering required function entry points.

You do need to make sure that the LIB files you link to use the same CRT as your app does, or things can go unexpectedly wrong.

Comment: I do not think we are understanding each other. Your answer tells me you know about this, but I am probably not understanding. My Runtime Library is "Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)" and my linker input is "cg.lib cgD3D9.lib Winmm.lib wininet.lib fbxsdk_20113_1d.lib d3d9.lib d3dx9.lib dinput8.lib dxguid.lib" Does this look correct? The reason for this is I assume mixing debug and release libraries cause problems.

Comment: Check out Hans's answer for adjunct information here.  The `/Mxxx` flag determines what only CRT version **your current project** link to - every app has to link to the CRT.  Any **other** libraries that you wish to use are named in your project's properties - they can be static or dynamic, but you need to make sure your app's CRT is DLL-ready if you plan to link to any DLLs.  Any clearer?

Comment: I believe I am understanding this better :) thank you for your patience, guys. Specifying /Mxxx on your project does not affect the way the linker accepts input, it changes how it links to the CRT?

Comment: You got it, yes. Take a look at that article @James referenced, that is the list of candidates for your CRT linkage.

Comment: I am studying this page here, and it doesn't seem to having anything about mixing static and release libraries. My objective is to dynamically link fbxsdk_20113_1d.lib (which has a DLL with it) and statically link cg.lib (which does not have a DLL.) I am using none of the libraries on that page for my project, so this is not making much sense.
I'm trying to dynamically link to I feel like such a burden for not getting this :/

Comment: Your terminology is mixed in that comment - `static/dynamic`, `debug/release` are the pairings you need to worry about.  If you are doing **any** dynamic linking, you need to use CRT for DLLs (not static CRT).  If you are mixing debug and release libraries, your mileage may vary and I'd expect problems.

Comment: I place the CRT libraries listed in that link into my linker? How does that work? I'm questioning what the compiler does automagically and what I have to work out. There is no such thing as "/MTd cg.lib /MTd cgD3D9.lib /MDd fbxsdk_20113_1d.lib" ?

Comment: No, your CRT is selected as I described in the answer above.  You cannot do what you are trying to do here, which is change the linkage of libraries after they are already built.  You should have debug and release versions of everything you need to worry about I would have thought? In which case you link to the same LIBs as your build uses (i.e. find out are you running a Release or Debug build of your app?  then use those LIBs).

Comment: I do not seem to have a different debug/release library for cg.lib, likewise for static/dynamic. The only way I can use cg.lib is to staticly link (which is what the examples for it do.) I'm assuming the compiler will detect this library is static, and incorporate it accordingly?

Comment: Not the compiler - the linker - but otherwise, yes.  Compiler only cares about external function declarations, it's at link-time that a particular version of an external funciton gets picked up.

Comment: Guys this is seriously not making very much sense, you must understand I'm pretty uneducated when it comes to the linker. FBX SDK (the one I am wanting to link to dynamically) documentation tells me to set the project to /MDd, which makes sense. However, I'm not understanding where to go in and link cg.lib **staticly** and not dynamically like the other. Your help is very much appreciated, please know this! :)

Comment: You *can't do this* if FBX SDK comes only as static libraries.  Before 2011.3 there was only static libraries.  Info from http://area.autodesk.com/forum/autodesk-fbx/fbx-sdk/fbx-sdk-faq/.  What version are you on?

Comment: 2011.3.1 is the version I am on, and it comes with DLLs so I am assuming it is dynamic. I can't do both static and dynamic linking? Why not? FBX SDK doesn't affect Nvidia's CG library, so why should linking the two to the same project affect it?

Comment: You should be able to do this - pick the dynamic .LIB files when you want to use a given library as a DLL, pick the static .LIB file when you want static linkage for a given library. I doubt Autodesk supports this officially, but it could work.  What you cannot do is cherry-pick some functions from a DLL and half from the matching static library.

Comment: They should be the same library. I'd like to use the DLL from FBX SDK and staticly link cg.lib... It is imperative to my project I learn how to do this, because at one point I will _need_ to dynamically link Qt.

Comment: What is `CG.LIB`?  If that's the FBX library then you are out of luck.  A given library cannot be both used by your project both statically and as a DLL.  If CG.LIB is *not* the FBX library, then just use the static CG.LIB, and the version of FBX.LIB that works dynamically, per the Autodesk docs (which I do not have).

Comment: cb.lib is for Nvidia's CG FX library (a compatible shader language that compiles multiplatform) I _am_ putting cg.lib and the appropriate FBX SDK lib into the linker, but it's still claiming heap corruption. The linker doesn't even resolve cb.lib, in fact. It seems it is not reading it, but it detects it...

Comment: If I were you I would try to get a working config (all static?  hopefully you still have this option?), then change one setting at a time until it breaks. There are too many SDKs here that I don't know for me to give you exact info on what libs you should be using to do what you want.

Comment: Nvidia's CG FX - cg.lib - static linking....
Autodesk FBX SDK - fbxsdk_20113_1.lib - dynamic linking (it is beefy and not needed very often, but still very important)....Direct3D9 - d3d9.lib - dynamic for sure. That is a no brainer.

Comment: Soon I will have to link Qt dynamically as a GUI framework, and that will need to be dynamic for legal reasons. This is why I am trying to figure out how to link both dynamic and static in the same project, which the linker seems to do automatically.

Answer (score 5):

No, you're mixing it up.  The /MD vs /MT options is only relevant to which CRT version you link.  There are two, the static version (/MT) which you should use only if you don't use any DLLs in your project.  And the DLL version, a version that every binary in your process can share so that you won't have heap allocation misery.  The kind of misery you get into when memory is allocated by one module and freed by another.

Choosing your own libraries is entirely up to you.  Mixing and matching is fine, the linker just gets another kind of .lib.  An import library instead of a static library.  Just keep in mind to use /MD when you use DLLs.

Comment: This seems to be on the right track. Please read my comment on the answer above. I'm currently having a problem where my program crashes at the end of a destructor for seemingly no reason (and I know exactly where it crashes.) I'm 99% certain this is because I am mixing debug and release libraries. Is there a way to mix libraries, in the way you can specify to link static/dynamic/debug/release in any combination?

Comment: Heap corruption is by far the most common reason for a destructor crash.  But yeah, the specific warning I gave fits.  Mixing debug and release can cause misery with STL iterator debugging, but that usually bombs much sooner.

Answer (score 0):

The linker options your describing are for the CRT only. The static version will limit how you share memory between modules.

All other libraries you use will have be linked in based on the .lib files you provide(or not) to the linker.

There are 3 ways to use a MS library

1. statically link static library (.lib equivelant of an .a archive of .o)
2. statically link the stub (.lib compiler generated loadlib/getproc) of a dynamic library
3. manually load a dynamic library (loadlib/getprocaddress)